# Заменить пробелы перед знаками препинания

Tags: java

Пользователь вводит какой нибудь текст

```
System.out.println("   привет   ,   как    дела  ?   ");
```

Как используя replaceAll на выходе получить `"привет, как дела?"`, что бы удалить все пробелы, я использую trim() и регулярки, но проблема в удаление пробелов перед знаками препинания, то есть я хочу взять `"\\s\\p{Punct}"` и заменить пробел со знаком пунктуации, только на знак пунктуации без пробела

```
String result = input.replaceAll("(\\s+)" , " ").replaceAll("\\s\\p{Punct}" , " ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "   привет   ,   как    дела  ?   ";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll("\\s(\\p{Punct})","$1").trim());
```

Вывод:

> привет, как дела?

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг будет интересен альтернативный способ решения задачи, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(modify("   привет   ,   как    дела  ?   "));
    }

    private static String modify(String original) {
        return original.trim()
                       .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
                       .replaceAll("\\s(?=\\p{Punct})", "");
    }
}
```

Здесь используется `non-capturing group via zero-width positive lookahead`.